# Unexpected aliasing of 'this' to local variable

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I get Eslint error: `Unexpected aliasing of 'this' to local variable. eslint(@typescript-eslint/no-this-alias)` on the code bellow:

```js
class LinkedList {
  value: number;
  next: LinkedList | null;

  constructor(value: number) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
  }

  reverse(): LinkedList {
    let current: LinkedList | null = this; // Unexpected aliasing of 'this' to local variable. eslint(@typescript-eslint/no-this-alias)
    let prev: LinkedList | null = null;
    while (current !== null) {
      const next = current.next as LinkedList;
      current.next = prev;
      prev = current;
      current = next;
    }
    return prev!;
  }
}
```

I want to resolve this without ignoring the error.
I have read [Eslint document](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-this-alias/) but didn't help much.

Comment: Added relevant eslint tags since TypeScript isn't producing the error you're talking about.

Comment: You might want to [edit] to clearly ask a question.  The existing answer seems to think it's "how can I prevent this error from occurring" but that's apparently not what you mean.

Comment: Do you think that your code is improper or low quality? If it is, I'd say that has nothing to do with the the initial value of the local. The very rule documentation you yourself linked explains that the intent of the rule is unrelated to your scenario

Answer (score -1):

add `// @ts-ignore` before `let current: LinkedList | null = this;`

e.g.

```
// @ts-ignore
let current: LinkedList | null = this;
```

Edited:

add a rule in `.eslintrc.cjs`

```
{
   "@typescript-eslint/no-this-alias": "off"
}
```

Comment: I don't want to ignore the error Eslint raises. Doing so defeats the whole purpose of using Eslint.